# Как именно скомпиировать программу, чтобы её можно было запустить?

Tags: java

Создал небольшую программу, но не знаю, как именно скомпилировать программу, чтобы запускать с компьютера, а не с консоли.
Ещё я не знаю, как в Java настраивать дизайн ведь это back-end язык, значит его надо с чем-то объеденять?

Comment: Java не только Back-end)) Есть """"""неплохие"""""" для фронт-енда библиотеки (штатные): Java Swing и JavaFX (последнее - это новая библиотека)

Comment: Java для front-end это сильно конечно))

Comment: А как скомпилировать программу? Чтобы можно было запускать.

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич ха. На JavaFX написал приложение для принятия заказов для кухни)

Comment: @Antonio112009 Ну и вы хотите сказать, что там frontend по меркам 2к19?)) Обычный фронт 2013-15) Я же не сказал, что нельзя..)

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич Да я смеюсь) JavaFX - Front-end of XXIII-века)

Comment: Если вы освоили Java, то для "кнопочных" приложений проще использовать WinForm C#. Кнопочки и примитивная логика делается за 10-15 минут. Просто делать Executable Java приложения с GUI не комильфо. Этим как правило занимаются люди плотно сидящие на Java, которым лень менять IDE и язык программирования. Как говорили выше, Java более предпочтителен для Back-end приложений.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно тебя интересует преобразование проекта в `.exe` файл или в (не помню что) для мака. Тебе поможет с этим Maven или `launch4j`.

Почитай данную статью. Автор статьи расскажет как сделать все на мавене: https://habr.com/post/131164/

Comment: .dmg (.apk, .app)

Comment: Тогда AndroidStudio или VisualStudio

Comment: @NewView Это уже IDE))